# Como hacer un bucle for para diccionario en Python

Tags: bucle-for

help, tengo el siguiente código. Necesito descargar varias imágenes de un servidor. Lo cual necesito cambiar los ultimos digitos del link, por ejemplo www.repositorio/imagen**0800**.gif para ww.repositorio/imagen**0810**.gif y así sucesivamente.

Intente hacer un requests para entrar a la pagina y descargar la imagen, e intente implementar un diccionario con los valores para sean reemplazados en un bucle y cambien los valores.

Pero no funciona, por favor podrian ayudarme como es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Probablemente no estoy entendiendo el funcionamiento del for

```
import requests
   
data={'1':'0800',
      '2':'0810',
      '3':'0820',
      }
{
for hora in data:
url_imagen = "http://satelite.cptec.inpe.br/repositoriogoes/goes16/class_nuvens/class_nuvens_web/2020/10/S11632408_20201021"+data+".gif" 
}


nombre_local_imagen = "imagen_descargada.jpg" # El nombre con el que queremos guardarla
imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(imagen)
```

Mi otro problema seria tambien que tiene que guardarse con nombres diferentes, **imagen001, imagen002, imagen003**... y así

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay varios temas principales.

El primero es el for en un `dict`,

si tú haces `for` en un `dict`, iterará sobre los `keys` y no sobre los values

```
data={
    '1':'0800',
    '2':'0810',
    '3':'0820',
}

for hora in data:
    print(hora)
```

podrás notar que solo imprimirá `1, 2, 3` que son los valores que tomará.

Para iterar sobre los `values` necesitas hacer

```
for hora in data.values():
    print(hora)
```

Eso iterará sobre los valores y mostrará `0080, 08010`

El segundo es que debes concatenar el valor y no el arreglo, de hecho eso te mostraría un error, dado que intentas concatenar un String con un dict.

Esto quedaría

```
url_imagen = "http://satelite.cptec.inpe.br/repositoriogoes/goes16/class_nuvens/class_nuvens_web/2020/10/S11632408_20201021"+hora+".gif"
```

El tercero es que todo necesita estar dentro del for, para eso ocuparemos tanto el `key` como el `value` y entonces usaremos la función del `dict` `ítems()` que regresará un `tuple` de `key, value`

```
for key, value in data.items():
    #key es el key del dict, en el primer caso '1' y value, el valor, en el primer caso '0800'
    url_imagen = "http://satelite.cptec.inpe.br/repositoriogoes/goes16/class_nuvens/class_nuvens_web/2020/10/S11632408_20201021"+ value +".gif" 
    nombre_local_imagen = "imagen_descargada" + key + ".jpg" # El nombre con el que queremos guardarla
    imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
    with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(imagen)
```

Como te darás cuenta, todo quedó dentro del for para que itere sobre todo el diccionario.

Comment: Impresionante! eres un genio. Era justamente eso lo que necesitaba entender y el resultado quedó perfecto. Muchas gracias!